# Mapping with parametrized type

Tags: java, morphia

I want to use MongoDB capped collections for storing events. These events all have a common superstructure, e.g.:

```
public class Event<T> {
    private final T body;
    private final String deviceMac;
    private final DateTime nowUtc;
    private final UUID eventUuid;
...
}
```

I want the capped collections to vary according to the parameter `T`, but I want the `Event<T>` super structure to be present in the collection, as well. More explicitly, I want to be able to map parametrized types as follows:

```
`Event<MessageIn>` --> db.messageIn
`Event<MessageOut>` --> db.messageOut
```

However, as I understand it, although Morphia can of course have multiple classes in a single collection, it cannot have a single class (however it be parameterized) in multiple collections -- that would seem to amount to multiple `@Entity` annotations on a single class.

An obvious but very lame route here is:

```
@Entity("messageIn")
public class MessageInEvent extends Event<MessageIn> {}
```

Is there a more elegant way to solve this?

Comment: I don't get the problem. You want to have (a) a single capped collection `event` or (b) multiple capped collections `messageIn`, `messageOut`,...? I assume (b). But then what's the problem with annotating the concrete implementations?

Comment: @xeraa, it's lame to have declare a subclass of `Event<Message>` just to put an `@Entity` annotation on it.

Comment: Leaving MongoDB aside, how do you create / instantiate your subclass with out declaring it? Once you create the class, I'd consider the additional entity annotation the minor problem

Comment: @xeraa, there's no need for the `MessageInEvent` class except for the annotation. It should just be `Event<MessageIn>`.

Comment: My bad, now I get your problem. But I'm pretty sure this is not possible. And probably also not desirable since it would lead to unexpected results — like "give me all events" failing (since there is no JOIN or UNION)

Comment: @xeraa, sure, you're right that the NoSQL model might encourage folks to store all the events in one collection to support the 'get all events' query. That said, that query doesn't make sense in my application; instead, I need to able to carefully tune the capped collections for particular data sets.